# Hide JSON Parse Errors in Express POST

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

I have this little Express server:

```
var express = require("express");

var app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.post("/hackme", (req, res) => {

    if(!req.body.foo) {
        return res.send({ error: 'oh no' });
    }

    return res.send({ lbxapi: '1.1' });
});

app.listen(3050, function() {
  console.log("Express running");
});
```

When I send an invalid JSON POST body to the following server, I the full error stack like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>SyntaxError: Unexpected string in JSON at position 18
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at JSON.parse (&lt;anonymous&gt;)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at parse (/home/jan/Desktop/linkbox_beta2_github/code/experiments/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:89:19)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at /home/jan/Desktop/linkbox_beta2_github/code/experiments/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:121:18
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at invokeCallback (/home/jan/Desktop/linkbox_beta2_github/code/experiments/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at done (/home/jan/Desktop/linkbox_beta2_github/code/experiments/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:213:7)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/home/jan/Desktop/linkbox_beta2_github/code/experiments/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:273:7)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:182:13)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1091:14)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:174:19)
        </pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

I dont want to user to see this. How can I hide it? An answer would be accepted that changes my server's code so that I dont see it anymore. Thank you!

Comment: Show us the part of your code where you used `JSON.parse`

Comment: Check the default error handler of express https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

Comment: Have you considered using the `process.env` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment by Ariel Alvarado (= using default error handler), I can answer my own question:

```
var express = require("express");

var app = express();
app.use(express.json());

// added this error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    console.error(err.stack)
    res.status(500).send('Something broke!')
});

app.post("/hackme", (req, res) => {

    if(!req.body.foo) {
        return res.send({ error: 'oh no' });
    }

    return res.send({ lbxapi: '1.1' });
});

app.listen(3050, function() {
console.log("Express running");
});
```